# Drupal view $fields variable can't show any output for "Row style output" in Theme

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

I have created a view that will display the output of a specific node.
My view's name is `test_view`. When i editing in `views-view-fields--test-view.tpl.php` file then it can't find `$fields`.
Again when editing
`views-view-fields--.tpl.php`,
`views-view-fields--page.tpl.php`,
`views-view-fields--page-1.tpl.php`,
`views-view-fields--test-view.tpl.php`,
`views-view-fields--test-view--page.tpl.php`,
`views-view-fields--test-view--page-1.tpl.php`
files then it also can't find `$fields` variable. 
But when I'm editing `views-view-fields.tpl.php` file then `$fields` variable is found.

What is the problem that I can't find that?

Need any kind of suggestions please...

Comment: Did you rescan the template files in your view?

Comment: yeah i have rescaned my template file always. But can't find any solution. Now i am in serious problem....

Answer (score 0):

`views-view-fields.tpl.php` is NOT one of the template files that you can override by creating a more specific file name.  See my similar question at https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/5412/overriding-views-view-fields-tpl-php